# Ruby Preferred Method for Adding Modules to Library Code?

Tags: ruby, module

What's the preferred method to add module functionality to library ruby code?

Consider the following:

```
module MyExceptions
    class SomethingBadHappenedTheLibarayDesignerDidntConsider < StandardError; end
end
```

How can I add `MyExceptions` module to a class that I don't control?

---

Update, in `my_library_class_exceptions.rb` I did:

```
class LibraryClass
    include MyExceptions
end
module MyExceptions
    class SomethingBadHappenedTheLibarayDesignerDidntConsider < StandardError; end
end
```

But the console returns: `NameError: uninitialized constant LibraryClass::MyExceptions`

Comment: You need to make sure your files are named correctly for autoloading to work. `MyExceptions` should be in "my_exceptions.rb".  Where have you put this file?

Comment: the library class I want to override is called `Samurai`, so I put all the code listed in my update in a empty filed called: `app/models/samurai.rb`

Comment: That file won't be loaded automatically.  When you reference `MyExceptions` and `MyExceptions` is not a known constant, auto-loading kicks in and a file name `my_exceptions.rb` is looked for.  You'll either have to include the file manually, or name it according to its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by fixing a few things, and changing a few things.

1. It turns out `LibraryClass` wasn't actually a class, but a module. So I changed:

   class LibraryClass
       include MyExceptions
   end

into to:

```
module LibraryClass
    module MyExceptions
        class SomethingBadHappenedTheLibarayDesignerDidntConsider < StandardError; end
    end
end
```

1. Then I moved `library_class.rb` into `lib\library_class_extensions.rb` and made sure that `lib` was part of the autoload path.
2. Then in an initializer, I called `require 'library_class_extensions'`

I think that's a better pattern for the behavior I was trying to accomplish anyway, since this really is more of library type code that `app/model` type code.

I'm up-voting the answers given by everyone, for their heroic efforts.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, you can open the definition of any class later and change it.

Below is a contrived example for overriding division to use a custom exception by reopening a previously created class.

```
class Foo
  def divide(a, b)
    a/b
  end
end

foo = Foo.new()
foo.divide(1, 0)

module MyExceptions
  class MyDivisionError < StandardError; end
end

class Foo
  include MyExceptions
  alias old_divide divide
  def divide(a, b)
    old_divide(a, b)
  rescue ZeroDivisionError
    raise MyDivisionError
  end
end

foo.divide(1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your update, the simple reason it doesn't work is the order: you use MyExceptions before it's defined.
The fixed version of your file - reopening the library class:

```
require 'thelib'

module MyExceptions
    class SomethingBadHappenedTheLibarayDesignerDidntConsider < StandardError; end
end
LibraryClass.class_eval do
    include MyExceptions
end
```

This class eval trick is arguably a safer way for reopening class than simply `class LibraryClass` again: it will warn you if you missed the classname.

BTW: I don't really see how you're planning the use MyException then.. that would probably mean some more monkey patching and/or wrapping parts of the library.

UPDATE: the above assumes you have `thelib.rb` in the same directory with at least the following content:

```
class LibraryClass
end
```

Comment: I reorganized per your suggestion, still getting the same `NameError`.

Comment: strange. I updated the answer by making sure we are on the same page. Please check again.